# style= "background: url('')" results in network call only in Chrome but not in IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I observed that when

```
style= "background: url('')"
```

is in the code, it will make a text/html network call with accept type as image only in Chrome but not in IE.

My Question is there a reason behind it or that is how IE Works?

Comment: No reason, implementation differences between browsers

Comment: Not sure, how did you make this test and with which version of IE you made a test? I set the 'background: url("img_tree.gif")' and you can see the request in the network tab of the IE 11 browser. See here: https://imgur.com/a/hKqjSIe

Comment: This happens only when the the method parameter is set it to empty string. empty string signifies current url. I'm on IE 11.

Comment: I don't know whats the logic behind passing the empty string for the URL parameter. I am not seeing it as an issue because if there is no URL then there is no reason for creating the request. I also check the Chrome and it is creating the document type request with 304 status.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60690013/8913947 It is be used to fetch few css properties from the current page and set it to the css attribute. Not sure how the whole thing works. Most of the examples online deals with images.

Comment: You should better link that sample instead of creating threads that look similar and marked as duplicate. that sample can help us to understand the issue in a better way and we can suggest whether same thing is possible in the IE browser or not.